# fft of a biosignal of unknown frequencyin python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to make a software so that I could use to analyse the data that I have on a file. I don't have information on the sampling rate at which the data was captured. Is there a way to find the frequency of my signal given that I can play around with the sampling rate of my signal? I tried writing a code to find the FFT of a sine wave that has a frequency of 100 Hz but when I plot fft of my signal, the frequency of the signal does not match the frequency on the fft axis. Here is the complete code for your reference.

```
from scipy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class FFTGUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.layout_init(self.master)

    def layout_init(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.title_label = Label(self.master, text="SIGNAL ANALYSER", font="-weight bold")
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.load_data_file_label = Label(self.master, text="LOAD DATA: ")
        self.load_data_file_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.load_data_file_button = Button(self.master, text="LOAD",command = self.askopenfilename)
        self.load_data_file_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.no_sample_label = Label(self.master, text="ENTER THE NUMBER OF SAMPLE POINTS: ")
        self.no_sample_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.no_sample_entry = Entry(self.master, text="Enter Sample")
        self.no_sample_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.sample_spacing_label = Label(self.master, text="ENTER THE SAMPLING SPACE (s):")
        self.sample_spacing_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.sample_spacing_entry = Entry(self.master, text="ENTER SPACE")
        self.sample_spacing_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.plot_graph_button = Button(self.master, text="PLOT", command = self.fft_data_plot)
        self.plot_graph_button.grid(row=4, columnspan =2)

    def askopenfilename(self):
        # get filename
        self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        # open file on your own
        #~ print self.filename
        if self.filename:
            return open(self.filename, 'r')

    def selectfile(self):
        self.file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
        if self.file != None:
            self.f= np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t', skiprows=0, unpack=True)
            #~ print type(f)
            return f

    def fft_data_plot(self):
        N = int(self.no_sample_entry.get())
        SAMPLE_SPACE_T = int(self.sample_spacing_entry.get())
        T = 1.0/SAMPLE_SPACE_T
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(self.filename)]
        lines = [float(i) for i in lines]

        #~ print lines
        yf = fft(lines)
        yf_power = np.abs(yf)**2
        energy_yf = 0

        for i in range(N/2):
            energy_yf += yf_power[i]
        #~ print energy_yf

        energy_nor_yf = []
        for i in range(N/2):
            temp_energy_nor_yf = (yf_power[i]/energy_yf)*100
            energy_nor_yf.append(temp_energy_nor_yf)
        #~ print energy_nor_yf


        plt.subplot(3,1,1)
        plt.plot(lines)

        plt.subplot(3,1,2)
        plt.plot(np.abs(yf))
        plt.ylim([0,100])
        plt.xlim([0,N/2])
        plt.subplot(3,1,3)
        plt.plot(energy_nor_yf)
        plt.ylim([0, max(energy_nor_yf)])
        plt.show()



root = Tk()
FFTGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The file I am trying to load and analyse can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/cosine100hz
This file is a simple cosine wave that I generated on excel and resulting data of the cosine wave was added in a text file so that it could be plotted and analysed. Unfortunately, I dont seem to know what the issue is and why I am not getting the desired frequency. I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I can not see the part of your code plotting power *versus the frequency*. You are plotting it versus component number, aren't you?

Comment: Hi abukaj, Yes, I am plotting against the component number.

Comment: How did you determine which component is 100 Hz?

Comment: That's what I am trying to find. I generated a sine wave of 100hz and saved the data in a file. I am new to signal processing. I might be missing something.

Comment: Oh, I understood that the peaks of the spectrum are not where you expect them.

Comment: Yes, exactly and the worst part is I don't understand why :(

Comment: Because you have to assign particular frequencies to components (which you can do knowing the number of samples and sampling ratio). See the updated answer.

Comment: The problem I am making has to do with sampling rate of the data and the number of samples of my data. If I generate a sin wave of 100Hz with a sample size of 500, I have to sample my signal at a sampling rate of 500 to get the exact output. The issue I am facing is when I have a sample rate which is much lower than the number of samples I have. How do I ensure that the frequency of my signal will be exact.

Comment: You can sample your signal with any sampling rate. Or rather any rate below 200Hz to avoid aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to obtain frequency from pure samples is to know some frequency present in your signal (e.g. power grid frequency artefact in EEG data).

[EDIT]

Since there is a known frequency in your signal, you may find the sampling ratio (or rather sampling interval). If you use `numpy.fft.fft()` (I guess `scipy.fft()` method is an alias for it), you can obtain frequencies of respective components with `numpy.fft.fftfreq()`.

The first argument of `numpy.fft.fftfreq(n, d=1.)` is the number of samples, while the second (`d`) is the sampling interval (1/f). You need to find an appropriate `d`.